# Php Script to check MySQL TABLE LOCK status

Tags: php, locking, mysql

I use mysqldump for MySQL Backup.

```
mysqldump --lock-tables....
```

The DB is about 2GB, hence mysqldump takes a long time.
If anyone tries to access the DB during backup, I would like to flash a message saying "the DB is being backed-up, please return back after 10 minutes"

My questions is using PHP script, how can I check if mysql table is locked or not.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Sanjay

Answer (score 2):

Prefer method will be setup replication,
and mysqldump on the slave instead on master (assuming only master is serving requests)

So, you never experiencing downtime

Answer (score 1):

If you have both read/write lock you can write a php script that try to access/write in a table, if it is locked the MySQL server will rise an error and you will be able to evaluate the code and send a message if the error is because the tables are locked.

HTH!

**EDIT:** You can take a look of the MySQL [GET_LOCK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html) function